# I'm getting an error while creating api with the data I pulled from the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to make a ".json" page with the data I pulled.
ut
Code

```js
app.get("/:user_id", async (req, res) => {
  let items = [];
  await msgData.find({ userId: req.params.user_id }).then((e) => {
    e.map((e) => {
      for (const [key, value] of e.msgChannelsMsgCount.entries()) {
        items.push({ guildId: e.guildId, channel: key, msgCount: value });
      }
    });
  });
  res.write(JSON.parse(items));
});
```

Mongoose Schema

```js
import { mongoose } from "./../../dist/tools.js";
const { model, Schema } = mongoose;

const schema = new Schema({
  userId: String,
  guildId: String,
  msgCount: Number,
  msgChannelsMsgCount: Map,
});

const msgdatas = model("msgdatas", schema);
export default msgdatas;
```

Mongo Output

```js
_id:626f1c8e9abf489a1bed71c1
userId:"337800833888681987"
guildId:"959946061915492373"
msgCount:30
msgChannelsMsgCount:Object
959946062095851523:7
970510925205475429:19
965236713314213889:1
__v:0
```

undefined:1
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse ()
at file:///C:/Users/imkys/OneDrive/Masa%C3%BCst%C3%BC/app/server/app.js:14:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

`res.write(JSON.parse(items));` to `res.write(items);` would work just fine.

Comment: node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Array

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
app.get("/:user_id", async (req, res) => {
  let items = [];
  await msgData.find({ userId: req.params.user_id }).then((e) => {
    e.map((e) => {
      for (const [key, value] of e.msgChannelsMsgCount.entries()) {
        items.push({ guildId: e.guildId, channel: key, msgCount: value });
      }
    });
  });
  res.write(JSON.stringify(items, null, ' '));
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Stack Overflow!

When you use `JSON.parse(<input>)` It read string input then turns that string into JS object format.

As an example:

```js
{
 "body": 5
}
//becomes
{
 body: 5
}
```

which makes it possible for you to use the objects' body as `object.body`

**To send json data you should use `res.json(items)` built-in express method**